# Issue Creating/Displaying a HTML5 Breadcrumb

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation

I'm trying to create a breadcrumb for my web application.

I have the following navigation menu within my .JSP file:

```
<nav class="nav">
<ul class="wrap">

    <li class="menu-nav--home"><a href="/home" title="home"><span class="icon-home"></span></a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/business">Business</a></li>
            <li><a href="/search">Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="/details">Search Deatils</a></li>
            <li><a href="/update">Change Records</a></li>
            <li><a href="/delete">Remove</a></li>
            <li><a href="/order">Order Deatils</a></li>
            <li><a href="/checkout">Checkout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

..And i have attempted to create a breadcrumb using HTML5 Microdata as per below:

```
 <div class="breadcrumb">
      <div class="wrap">
          <ol class="menu menu--hor">
            <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
                  <a href="/home" itemprop="url">
                      <span itemprop="title">Home</span>
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
                  <a href="/business" itemprop="url">
                      <span itemprop="title">Business</span>
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
                  <a href="/search" itemprop="url">                      
                      <span itemprop="title">Search</span>
                  </a>
              </li>  
              <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
                  <a href="/details" itemprop="url">
                      <span itemprop="title">Details</span>
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
                  <a href="/update" itemprop="url">
                      <span itemprop="title">Update</span>
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
                  <a href="/delete" itemprop="url">
                      <span itemprop="title">Delete</span>
                  </a>
              </li>  
              <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
                  <a href="/order" itemprop="url">
                      <span itemprop="title">New Order</span>
                  </a>
              </li>
              <li itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
                  <a href="/checkout" itemprop="url">
                      <span itemprop="title">Checkout</span>
                  </a>
              </li>
          </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My issue is, all items on the breadcrumb are being displayed, when, i only want the current location to be displayed.

**Current display:**

Home Business Search Details Update Delete New Order Checkout

**Preferred Display (when on Checkout page, for example)**

Home > Checkout

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE - 24/07/13

So, after a bit of Googling, it was clear some JS was missing, here is a first attempt.

```
    // Bread crumb script /////////////

var path = "";
var href = document.location.href;
var s = href.split("/");
for (var i=2;i<(s.length-1);i++) {
    path+="<A HREF=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf("/"+s[i])+s[i].length+1)+"/\">"+s[i]+"</A> / ";
}
i=s.length-1;
path+="<A HREF=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf(s[i])+s[i].length)+"\">"+s[i]+"</A>";
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + path;
document.writeln(url);
```

Which does appear to retrieve the current page/site.. however, does not place it below my Nav menu but rather in a new page that seems to crash my site.

Do it need some form of .append on a new DIV ?

Comment: I imagine i am missing some form of JavaScript / jQuery ?

Comment: Does that script retrieve the name of the current page? e.g. `Checkout`?

Comment: @Campari - Please latest version and issue here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852424/html-breadcrumb-displaying-then-losing-location-once-new-page-is-loaded/17853612?noredirect=1#comment26064740_17853612