# HTML Breadcrumb Displaying Then Losing Location Once New Page Is Loaded

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have an issue with the breadcrumb on my site.

On page load, the Home is displayed (which is correct).. When i click on a link within my navigation menu, the breadcrumb is updated with say:

Home > New Page

However, when the New Page is loaded, the breadcrumb goes back to only displaying Home.

My Navigation JSP file:

```
<nav class="nav">
  <ul class="wrap">

    <li class="menu-nav--home">
      <a href="/home" title="home">
        <span class="icon-home"></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/business">Business</a></li>
      <li><a href="/search">Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="/details">Search Deatils</a></li>
      <li><a href="/update">Change Records</a></li>
      <li><a href="/delete">Remove</a></li>
      <li><a href="/order">Order Deatils</a></li>
      <li><a href="/checkout">Checkout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>

<div class="wrap breadcrumb">
  <div class="item">
    <a href="#home">Home </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
  createBreadcrumbs();      
}

function createBreadcrumbs() {
  $('.site-nav a').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
    $bc = $('<div class="item"></div>');

    $this.parents('li').each(function(n, li) {
      var $a = $(li).children('a').clone();
      $bc.prepend(' > ', $a);
    });

    $('.breadcrumb').html( $bc.prepend('<a href="/">Home </a>') );    
    return false;
  });
```

Any help appreciated.

I have attempted to follow the advice found here - [jquery - dynamic breadcrumb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416842/jquery-dynamic-breadcrumb)

Thanks

Comment: Have you got a live link for it?

Comment: @RobSterlini - Hi, unfortunately not, i believe the jsFiddle in the link above replicates the error. Within my jQuery, if i return true, the page will redirect on click of an item within the nav menu.. and the breadcrumb will update before opening the new page, then go back to displaying Home on load of the new page.

Comment: How deep do these breadcrumbs go? I'm not sure that jQuery and javascript is the best way to tackle these issues. Are you working in PHP?

Comment: @RobSterlini - I would say 3 levels. My site is only using HTML5 and jQuery.

Comment: After putting in some indentation, I see you have both invalid markup and your jQuery is missing the last `}`. The markup error is in the 'nav' where you missed a starting `li` tag before the nested `ul` tag. I doubt this is causing this problem, but it is something you should fix nevertheless.

Comment: You seem to be forgetting a `);` behind `$(function() { createBreadcrumbs(); }` too.

Comment: @Sumurai8 - thanks for your advice. I have amended the markup and added the li tag. For some reason my post deleted the last } from my functions and the ); from the ready. I can confirm they are in fact there, and errors remains.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of errors in your code. First of all, you are forgetting a `);` in the following code:

```
$(function() {
  createBreadcrumbs();      
} ); //HERE!
```

and you might have forgotten to copy the last `}` to this question. I've added that one in here. You are attaching a handler to links that are a child of an element with the `site-nav` class. There is no such thing in your code. Change that to `.nav a`.

```
function createBreadcrumbs() {
  $('.nav a').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
    $bc = $('<div class="item"></div>');

    $this.parents('li').each(function(n, li) {
      var $a = $(li).children('a').clone();
      $bc.prepend(' > ', $a);
    });

    $('.breadcrumb').html( $bc.prepend('<a href="/">Home </a>') );    
    return false;
  });
}
```

Edit: If you want this to actually display something, you'll need to load the page with ajax and shove the resulting html into the DOM.

Comment: thanks for your advice. The ); was missing off my post. Additionally, my  $('site-nav a').on('click'.. was from an earlier version, hence the error. I have updated to $('.nav a').on('click'.. prior to posting this messege.

Comment: With return false, breadcrumb will display correctly if a link in the Nav menu is clicked, however, that subsequent page will not load... If return true, the subsequent page will load, however, the breadcrumb on the newly loaded page will only say Home.. So, as you have advised, i may need an ajax... Any ideas of how i can achieve this?

Comment: I would personally create the breadcrumbs on the server-side, because that way it will always be a correct tree structure. Doing it on the client side in conjunction with ajax will require a lot of code to get it right (or you'll end up with `home > page 2 > page 3 > home > page 1 > page 3 > home` or something stupid like that). This is [the jQuery ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: I'm not opposed to developing it server-side. Do you know of any how-to's? I'm using a MVC framework with HTML5, jQuery and Java.

Comment: I've taken your comments on board and have gone about creating the simple breadcrumb for my site the long way round. I have followed a new strategy as my site is only 3 levels - Home > Search > Details... Please see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17918487/saving-page-tilte-in-a-variable-so-accessible-after-post